# How to remove duplicate values in an individual column for multiple columns at once

Tags: excel, duplicates

**How do I remove duplicate values within individual columns across all of my columns at once?**

If I select the `Remove Duplicates` tool in Excel with multiple columns selected, it assumes I'm looking for duplicates *across* columns.

What I want is to remove duplicates in *individual columns*, but I don't want to have to click each of my columns individually.

- For example, assume I have a spreadsheet with 500 columns. 
  I want to remove all duplicate values in Column 1 ("A"), and then remove all duplicate columns in Column 2 ("B") and so forth through Column 500.

---

What I've Tried:

1. Record Macro. The results:

   ```
   ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
   Columns("A:A").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$582").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
   ```

   As you can see, for some reaosn it auto selects column "A". I don't know how to make it generically select the letter of the column I've selected. Sooo...
2. I tried the following:

   ```
   Col = Split(ActiveCell(1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   ActiveSheet.Range("Col1:Col1581").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
   ```

   But it also does not work.

How would I go about doing this??

---

I'm using MS Excel 2010 (Professional Plus)

Comment: What have you tried? Should be a pretty simple macro - just turn on the macro recorder, remove duplicates from A, then B, and stop the recorder. You should then have a nice skeleton of how to do it.  Look up "loop through columns in worksheet" and see what you can do.  Then, if you're still stuck, we're happy to help with the code.

Comment: @BruceWayne I updated the question to reflect what I've tried. A simple recording macro didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply loop through columns and remove duplicates from that column, say `A` through `Z`, you can do this:

```
Sub removeDups()
Dim col As Range
For Each col In Range("A:Z").Columns
    With col
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    End With
Next col
End Sub
```

You can tweak that as needed, whether setting a range to equal your selection, or extending the range to, say, `AZ`.